# Problems while installing gource

Tags: apt, software-installation

i am using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS.
i was trying to install gource but no 64 bit version of it availble. i downloaded i386 version of itand this is the error

[image]

is this because one cannot install i386 packages on amd64? then how do i rum gource on my machine?

Comment: *gource* should be available in the Ubuntu Universe archives:  Have you tried to execute  `sudo apt-get install gource`?

Comment: i did... it all went smoothly... i had to run sudp apt-get install -f but this is error that i receive when i type gource  "mymac@juggernaut:~$ gource
gource: directory not supported
Try 'gource --help' for more information.

mymac@juggernaut:~$ 
"

Comment: Then it seems that *gource* is installed, but that you have a different problem related to the configuration.

Comment: shouldn't `gource` be run within a directory containing a repo (Git, Mercurial, Bazaar or SVN version control repository)?

Comment: i really did not understand what you said @Ron ... pls break it down for me

Comment: Then I don't think you fully understood the purpose of gource. What to you want to use gource for?

Comment: i'll be honest here... i really dont know ... i just waneted to see the visualizations for myself

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the `gource` package:

> **OpenGL-based 3D visualisation tool for source control repositories.**
>
> The repository is displayed as a tree where the root of the repository is the centre, directories are branches and files are leaves. Contributors to the source code appear and disappear as they contribute to specific files and directories.

Thus, `gource` needs to be run in a directory that contains a version control repository, as it visualizes changes to this repository.

Version control systems, such as Git, Subversion or others, are used to keep track of changes made in software projects, especially useful when multiple people are working on the same project, as most VCS allow you to create a *branch*, i.e. a copy of the project at a certain point in time, which you can work at, and which can later be merged back to the master branch, allowing you to work without other people breaking your stuff.

They also allow you to revert the state of the repository to a certain point in time, in case you screwed up.

And that is where your error appears: If you run `gource` outside a directory managed by a version control system, it obviously won't work.